# ME keystore to SE keystore

Tags: java, keystore, gemalto

I have a problem because I lost original SE keystore file. Now I only have .bin file which contains ME keystore. Does anyone know how can I convert ME keystore back to SE keystore. For SE to ME I used keytool and mekeytool. It would be even enough if anyone knows the "key" which is used to change ME to SE and I can do it manualy if there is not tool for ME to SE.
I need to get original ME key, so that I can unlock my Gemalto BGS5 modul.

Comment: What are "SE" and "ME"? I'm assuming these are types of keystore, but I've never heard of them before.

Comment: You have a java program called keytool which makes you a SE keystore. Then you use mekeytool to convert it to ME keystore. You can also create SE keystore with IDE like Eclipse and NetBeans. But I don't know what is the diffrence betwen these types, just that ME is 2 times bigger.
Links about it from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/jme-sdk-3.0-mac/UserGuide-html/z400007747110.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html

Comment: As far as I can see, you are in a bind. mekeytool does not appear to support any kind of exporting. It seems that it is able to convert a JKS keystore (referred to as SE keystore) to its own format (J2SE), but not export it. That's what [this source](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/com/sun/midp/mekeytool/MEKeyTool.java.html) suggests anyways.

Comment: BTW, this keystore only seems to store public keys (CA certificates)... You haven't really lost much. You can just rebuild it using keytool by adding trusted entires to a new SE keystore.

Comment: I tryed to rebuild it with the same input parameters but it didn't work. If I don't get the original SE keystore I can't delete it from the machine and I can't upload or run any Java program that doesn't have the same signature.